# SQL exclude values that are in another data frame column

Tags: sql

Say I have two tables

First_table

| id | occupation |
| --- | --- |
| efg | carpenter |
| hjk | teacher |
| moo | scientist |
| dss | engineer |

Second_table

| id | state |
| --- | --- |
| efg | PA |
| loi | DE |
| moo | NY |
| nbw | MD |

Now I want to write a query that gets rid of the rows of the first table, if first_table.id is in second_table.id. So the output would be

| id | occupation |
| --- | --- |
| hjk | teacher |
| dss | engineer |

One way I could do this is by writing a where clause, and then put parameters into the where clause such as

```
where first_table.id != moo and first_table.id != efg
```

but that would require me to write some logic to figure out which data to exclude, and I would want all the logic to be in a query anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like `not exists`:

```
select f.*
from first_database f
where not exists (select 1 from second_database s where s.id = f.id);
```